# How to add a static row to a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, row, aspxgridview

ok so my goal is to add only 1 static row under the gridview headr EXAMPLE:

|coloumnHeader1|coloumnHeader2|coloumnHeader3|coloumnHeader4|

|----------------------static Row---------------------------|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|
|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|DataBoundField|

|----------------------Footer-------------------------------|

my hunch is its got something with RowDataBound but that's as far as i have got.

i guess i need to explain myself better : what i want to do is the equivalent to adding a new HeaderRow...
thnx for all the helpers :D

FOUND THE ANSWER:
after a lot of googling i found what i was looking for ,
on the asp

```
<asp:GridView OnPreRender="grd_Pre" CssClass="table" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   >
```

in the code behind

```
 protected void grd_Pre(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gv = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.ColumnSpan = 3;
    tc.Text = "GridView Header";
    tc.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center");
    gv.Cells.Add(tc);
    this.GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gv);
}
```

Comment: what is you problem?? or where you struggling??

Comment: I have already solved this problem i posted my solution after the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOUND THE ANSWER:
after a lot of googling i found what i was looking for ,
on the asp

```
<asp:GridView OnPreRender="grd_Pre" CssClass="table" ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
   >
```

in the code behind

```
 protected void grd_Pre(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gv = new GridViewRow(0, 0, DataControlRowType.Header, DataControlRowState.Normal);
    TableCell tc = new TableCell();
    tc.ColumnSpan = 3;
    tc.Text = "GridView Header";
    tc.Attributes.Add("style", "text-align:center");
    gv.Cells.Add(tc);
    this.GridView1.Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(0, gv);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mention, you can probably insert a row during the RowDataBound event, but that would be messy.

Depending on the data structure you bind to your grid, you may be able to insert your static row to your data structure.  I've even some implementations where the query is modified to return a static row, so you end up with something like:

```
select field1, ... , fieldN from table
union
select 'static 1', ...
```

Instead, can you add your static row as part of your header template?

It's hard to answer this properly without seeing more your code.

Comment: yes i have thought of editing the header template as well but i would much rather to add said static row during the RowDataBound, there is no code , there is just a gridview that his data is from the codebehind...