# My Asp.net gridview deletes the static rows when I add rows dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I used the code as per [Thiru's post](http://www.dotnettwitter.com/2012/01/group-total-and-grand-total-part-2.html?showComment=1378112771205#c2143172203925583872) to dynamically add a group separator row as shown in his post. This was also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400134/how-to-add-a-static-row-to-a-gridview) as a solution to a previous issue but my problem extends beyond this point. I have a column of checkboxes that I need to store their values in a database. So I loop over the gridView rows using something like foreach(GridView row).

Debugging my code, I realized that if I added 4 rows dynamically then the loop exits before visiting the last 4 rows of data. In other words, if my datasource originally retrieves 24 rows to be displayed on the gridview and I added 4 dynamic rows as group separator rows, the total length of the array of gridView rows (attribute of the gridview object) remains 24 not 28.

Comment: Could you post some of your code?